# How do I align this?

Tags: html, css

So I have been trying to align this. Trying to play around with the codes but still no luck

```
.image{

float: left;
padding-left: 25%;
padding-top: 20px;
}
 .side-menu{
float: right;
 }
div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="image">
    <img src="egg.jpg" width="400" height="400">
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
        <h1>Ingredients</h1>
        <p>
        2 eggs<br>
        2 tbsp (30 mL)milk (1%)<br>
        Pinch salt<br>
        Pinch pepper</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not clear enough with what your problem is, and you would probably need to provide some html tags.

Comment: You're being downvoted becuase it isn't clear at all as to what you want. Where is your html markup? What is wrong with it and how do you want it displayed?

Comment: Please, take some time to format your code and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What are you trying to align? Image on left and ingredients on right? Always?

Comment: i want them next to eachother. the img on the left and next to it is the ingredients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your two child divs inside a container div then give both child divs `float:left;` property will display both child divs side by side.

Here is the code: 
**CSS**

```
.container {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}

.image{
float: left;
padding-left: 25%;
padding-top: 20px;
}
 .side-menu{
float: left;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="egg.jpg" width="400" height="400">
    </div>

    <div class="side-menu">
        <h1>Ingredients</h1>
        <p>
        2 eggs<br>
        2 tbsp (30 mL)milk (1%)<br>
        Pinch salt<br>
        Pinch pepper</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How will i put this under the Ingredients? Many thanks                                         <div class="instructions">
     <h2>Instructions</h2>
     <p>
      <b>STEP 1</b> Whisk eggs, milk, salt and pepper in small bowl.
     </p>
</div>